# Swift Firebase -is there a way to directly set Auth.auth().currentUser && Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

The main question is it possible to set a nil `Auth` object from a saved `Auth` object:

```
let oldAuth = Auth.auth().currentUser
let oldAuthId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

let newAuth = Auth.auth().currentUser
let newAuthId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

newAuth?.delete { (error) in
    if let error = error { return }

    // *** Auth is now nil ***

    // set the nil Auth to the oldAuth
    Auth.auth().currentUser = self.oldAuth
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid = self.oldAuthId
}
```

The above code doesn't work and I would like to get it to work but the question would be why would you want to do something like that. The explanation is below.

I'm using anonymous sign-in and create an account sign-in and ran into a problem.

userA first signs in anonymously and they get a `User?` value(`Auth.auth().currentUser`) and userId value (`Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`):

```
var anonymousUser: User? // "object123"
var anonymousUserId: String? // "id456"

Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion: { [weak self](authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error) in

        if let error = error { return }

        guard let _ = authDataResult?.user.uid else { return }

        self?.anonymousUser = authDataResult?.user // "object123"
        self?.anonymousUserId = authDataResult?.user.uid // "id456"
    })
}
```

Later on the user than creates an account and gets an entirely new `User?` value(`Auth.auth().currentUser`) and userId value (`Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`). After they create the account there is a problem updating a ref. Instead of them continuing on they decide to cancel and would rather stay an anonymous user.

```
var realUser: User? // "objectABC"
var realUserId: String // "idXYZ"

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { [weak self] (authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error) in

        if let error = error { return }

        guard let realUserId = authDataResult?.user.uid else { return }

        self?.realUser = authDataResult?.user // "objectABC"
        self?.realUserId = authDataResult?.user.uid // "idXYZ"

        let someRef = Database.database().reference().child("some").child(realUserId).childByAutoId()
        someRef?.updateChildValues(someDict, withCompletionBlock: { [weak self] (error, ref) in

        if let error = error {

             self?.problemAlert()

            // *** PROBLEM *** present alert giving the user the option to cancel or continue on as an anonymous user
            return 
        }
    })
})
```

The way I do it now is if the user decides to cancel I delete the user object from FB:

```
func problemAlert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController ...

    let tryAgainAction = UIAlertAction...

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action) in

        // *** COMPLETELY DELETE THE USER ***
        let user = self.realUser
        user?.delete { (error) in
            if let error = error { return }

            // *** Auth is now nil ***

            // *** set Auth back to the anonymousUser values but this doesn't work ***
            Auth.auth().currentUser = self.anonymousUser
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid = self.anonymousUserId
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is the anonymous user login object has now been replaced with the real user object because the new account was created. But because I deleted the `User`? inside the alert's cancel action userA is now nil.

Is there a way I can set the nil Auth object doing something like this:

```
// this doesn't work
Auth.auth().currentUser = anonymousUser
Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid = anonymousUserId
```

The work around can simply be just don't delete the newly created current user and let userA continue on as them but that isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to allow the user to create their identified account (with either a social provider or email+password) without signing them in, and then [link the new account with their existing anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking).

So for email+password, instead of calling `createUser(withEmail: , password:)`, you'd instead create their credentials using

```
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

And then link them with:

```
user.link(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
  // ...
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh I never knew that, all this time I thought you had to do it the way I was ding it. This is the same way you link a phoneNumber to an already existing email sign up. Thanks!!!

Comment: Quick question, what about logging in an anonymous user. Say you have a registered user, they logout, they’re now an anonymous user, they log back in. Are you supposed to link the anonymous user with the logged in user like indoor answer?

Comment: When you log out for Firebase Authentication, you log out from all providers, so also from the anonymous provider.

Comment: Maybe I set this up wrong. The way my app works is once the app is downloaded the user is brought inside the main app (think of yelp). They can scroll through reviews etc. But to see ratings from other users they need a uid (Firebase rules). If no uid then you can’t see ratings so once they’re in I let them browse around as an anonymous user. Same thing with someone who is logged out. Rules eg {ratings: “read”: “auth.uid != null” }. They also need to have a uid to see the other user’s profile photo etc. Anonymous signin happens in the background, user doesn’t know. That’s all I could think of

Comment: Basically wether the user downloads the app for the first time or they logout they’re going to need a uid to see posts from other users so I sign them in as an anonymous user in the background

Comment: There's no way to regain the UID of an anonymous user, and the UID of an anonymous user is lost once they sign out. I'm afraid I don't know how to further apply that to your use-case. Consider unlinking, instead of signing them out? But I've never done anythint like that myself.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’m going to look into unlinking, that might be a good option. Enjoy your day!